# Matplotlib "dictionary changed size during iteration" error when creating subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, weak-references

I wrote a function that plots a figure consisting of two subplots of different sizes:

```
def draw_plot(data, function, sigma_value):

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 5)
    ax1 = subplot(gs[0, 0:3])  
    ax2 = subplot(gs[0, 3:5], sharey=ax1)                
    gs.update(wspace=0.05)
    ...
```

I should mention that this is a module-level function, so at the top of that module I make imports

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
```

When I run `myplot.draw_plot(...)`, I get `RuntimeError`. The thing is this behaviour is inconsistent. I can call the function, say, three times, and the first two times I get the error, whereas the third time it runs OK.

The Traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "myplot.py", line 105, in draw_plot
    ax1 = subplot(gs[0, 0:3])                 
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 766, in subplot
    a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 779, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 8380, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 467, in __init__
    self.cla()
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 910, in cla
    self._shared_y_axes.clean()
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 1493, in clean
    for key, val in mapping.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Obviously I've been trying to figure out myself what is going on, so following the `Traceback` I checked the `clean()` function in `cbook.py`.

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Clean dead weak references from the dictionary
    """
    mapping = self._mapping
    for key, val in mapping.items():
        if key() is None:
            del mapping[key]
            val.remove(key)
```

In the function I added a line that would print `mapping.items()` and I noticed that the error occurs when there are entries similar to `<weakref at 0480EBA0; dead>` among those items. I'm totally unfamiliar with weak references so I'm stuck again.

**EDIT 2**
It's certainly not a good solution but commenting out the `clean()` function body helps in my case without producing any new errors.

Comment: Great work figuring out the solution. You should add it yourself as an answer and accept it (so that this can be removed from the unanswered questions page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found a very recent post [Safely iterating over WeakKeyDictionary and WeakValueDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428026/safely-iterating-over-weakkeydictionary-and-weakvaluedictionary) that helps with a very similar issue.

So using answer given by Bakuriu I edited `close()` function as following

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Clean dead weak references from the dictionary
    """

    mapping = self._mapping
    for key, val in list(mapping.items()):  # iterate over list now        
        if key() is None:
            del mapping[key]
            val.remove(key)
```

and it seems to be working just fine!

**EDIT**

I've just found out that in a new version of `matplotlib` the function looks like this:

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Clean dead weak references from the dictionary
    """
    mapping = self._mapping
    to_drop = [key for key in mapping if key() is None]
    for key in to_drop:
        val = mapping.pop(key)
        val.remove(key)
```

Source:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py

Answer (score 1):

Just a short explanation of what is happening:

You looped over an iterable (list, dict, whatever) like this:

```
for somevalue in someiterable:
    #do something
```

And inside the loop you tried to structurally modify the iterable, meaning you added or removed values. This is not allowed because it would mess with the for loop. The solution to this is usually to iterate over a copy of the iterable, leaving you free to altering the original.

Comment: Oh, I didn't recognize it is a library function that causes this error... they should definitely fix this. I think the python3 version of many libraries is not that stable yet, it could be a problem introduced during porting.