# Safely iterating over WeakKeyDictionary and WeakValueDictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, weak-references

The documentation of *Python 3.2*'s `weakref` module's `WeakKeyDictionary` and `WeakValueDictionary` have a note on iterating over these containers:

> **Note:** Caution: Because a WeakKeyDictionary is built on top of a Python dictionary, it must not change size when iterating over it. This can be difficult to ensure for a WeakKeyDictionary because actions performed by the program during iteration may cause items in the dictionary to vanish “by magic” (as a side effect of garbage collection).

That seems rather dire as a specification of these container's behavior. Especially when running code that uses CPython's garbage collector (when using data structures that contain cycle) or using another Python implementation (e.g. Jython), then it sounds as if there is no safe way of iterating over these collections.

How can I safely iterate over these collections when the garbage collector may clear references at any point in my program? Having a solution for CPython is my priority but I'm interested about the issue on other implementations as well.

Is this maybe a safe way to iterate over a WeakKeyDictionary?

```
import weakref

d = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()

...

for k, v in list(d.items()):
    ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is actually safe to iterate over a `WeakKeyDictionary`, `WeakValueDictionary`, or `WeakSet` in Python 2.7 or Python 3.1+. [They put in an iteration guard](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1a2d3563f960bc284daf146a1b6944cb16167666) that prevents weakref callbacks from removing references from the underlying dict or set during iteration all the way back in 2010, but the docs never got updated.

With the guard in, if an entry dies before iteration reaches it, iteration will skip that entry, but it won't result in a segfault or a RuntimeError or anything. Dead entries will be added to a list of pending removals and handled later.

[Here's the guard](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/_weakrefset.py#L10) (not threadsafe, despite the comment):

```
class _IterationGuard:
    # This context manager registers itself in the current iterators of the
    # weak container, such as to delay all removals until the context manager
    # exits.
    # This technique should be relatively thread-safe (since sets are).

    def __init__(self, weakcontainer):
        # Don't create cycles
        self.weakcontainer = ref(weakcontainer)

    def __enter__(self):
        w = self.weakcontainer()
        if w is not None:
            w._iterating.add(self)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, e, t, b):
        w = self.weakcontainer()
        if w is not None:
            s = w._iterating
            s.remove(self)
            if not s:
                w._commit_removals()
```

[Here's where the WeakKeyDictionary weakref callback checks the guard](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/weakref.py#L356):

```
def remove(k, selfref=ref(self)):
    self = selfref()
    if self is not None:
        if self._iterating:
            self._pending_removals.append(k)
        else:
            del self.data[k]
```

[And here's where `WeakKeyDictionary.__iter__` sets the guard](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/weakref.py#L445):

```
def keys(self):
    with _IterationGuard(self):
        for wr in self.data:
            obj = wr()
            if obj is not None:
                yield obj

__iter__ = keys
```

The same guard is used in the other iterators.

---

If this guard did not exist, calling `list(d.items())` wouldn't be safe either. A GC pass could happen inside the `items` iterator and remove items from the dict during iteration. (The fact that `list` is written in C would provide no protection.)

---

Back in 2.6 and earlier, the safest way to iterate over a WeakKeyDictionary or WeakValueDictionary would have been to use `items`. `items` would return a list, and it would use the underlying dict's `items` method, which would have been (mostly?) not interruptible by GC. The dict API changes in 3.0 changed how `keys`/`values`/`items` worked, which is probably why the guard was introduced when it was.

Comment: "A GC pass could happen inside the items iterator and remove items from the dict during iteration. (The fact that list is written in C would provide no protection.)". That's not true. The GC would have to hold the GIL to update reference counts and call `__del__` methods, it can't do that concurrently with a C call which does not release the GIL. That's why most C calls are atomic in Python, no other Python code can run concurrently with them if they do not release the GIL.

Comment: @Eloff: But a WeakKeyDictionary's iterator is written in Python, not C. It's not the same as a regular dict iterator. (Also, CPython doesn't use a separate GC thread - it runs the GC inside normal threads. When the GC interrupts running Python code, it does so inside that code's own thread. That means we have to deal with reentrancy, not just thread-safety.)

Comment: I think you're right, invoking the iterator from C calls back into the interpreter, which could release and reacquire the GIL. GC could run in there as well then.

Answer (score 7):

To be safe you have to keep a reference somewhere. Using the idiom:

```
for k,v in list(d.items()):
```

is not completely safe because, even though it will work most of the time, during the last iteration of the loop the list may be garbage-collected.

The correct way would be:

```
items = list(d.items())
for k,v in items:
    #do stuff that doesn't have a chance of destroying "items"
del items
```

If you use a `WeakKeyDictionary` you could simply store the keys, and store values if you use `WeakValueDictionary`.

On a side note: in python2 `.items()` already returns a list.

Ultimately it depends on what do you mean by "safe". If you simply mean that the iteration will proceed correctly(iterating once on all the elements), then:

```
for k,v in list(d.items()):
```

is safe, because the iteration over the dictionary is actually performed by `list(d.items())`, then you are only iterating over the list.

If you, instead, mean that during the iteration elements should not "disappear" from the dictionary as side-effect of the `for`-loop, then you must keep a strong reference until the end of the loop, and this requires you to store the list in a variable before starting the loop.

Comment: Why would your first example be unsafe? The list will contain strong references to each key and value and during the last iteration, `k` and `v` hold strong references to the objects I'm interested in. So the list may be garbage collected even before the last iteration terminates. Is that right?

Comment: That's like saying that `for k,v in d.items()` is safe, because `k` and `v` hold strong-references to the objects. The iteration is unsafe if, inside the for-loop, there is a chance for the `k` and `v` to be deleted. For simple enough tasks iterating over the `WeakKeyDictionary` should be safe.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something, but how can the objects `k` and `v` reference be deleted? As long as these variables are in scope and not overidden, the referenced objects are safe. Or are you talking about removing all strong references to those objects during the last iteration? That would change the dictionary but won't be unsafe because the dictionary is not accessed after iteration has started. Can you give an example of what may go wrong during the last iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Convert to strong references without using iteration first.

```
items = []
while d:
    try:
        items.append(d.popitem())
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

If it loses some keys during the while loop, it shouldn't cause problems.

Then you can iterate over `items` instead. When you're done, `d.update(items)` to put them back, and then `del items`.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the garbage collector.

```
import gc

gc.disable()
try:
    items = list(d.items())
finally:
    gc.enable()
```

Then iterate over `items` instead.

Comment: It's definitely not as easy as that! 1st, this is not portable, not all Python implementations implement that interface. 2nd, maybe disabling garbage collection is a bad idea because the loop could run for a long time. 3rd, this will be buggy in concurrent applications as one thread could enable garbage collection while another is still iterating the dictionary.